# Android-Restarting a process in a current activity from an asyncTask postExecute in another

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an activity that lets a user upload a photo to the web and instead of having them wait indefinitely for the image to upload I have it being done in an asynctask that handles the image upload. When the user presses the button to upload the image the I have the activity that uploads the image close and the app goes back to the earlier activity which has its own downloading process. What Im trying to figure out is what to do in the asynctask onPostExecute to get the download process in the other activity to run again. I tried just using this:

```
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    if(result!=null){
    Main.DownloadManager.startDownloading();
      }else if(result==null){
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Upload failed",timetoshow).show();
              }
          }
```

But I get no response in the main activity because I know Im not actually calling the running activity but just calling the method.....somewhere thats not instantiated or running....or at least thats what I think this does. So I guess my question is how can I pass the message to run the startDownloading() method from the asynctask of the closed activity in the currently running Main activity.  Any help would be super much appreciated.

EDIT:

I was able to solve this by implementing one of the solutions bellow:

```
 @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    if(result!=null){
    CustomContextClass.*Main*.DownloadManager.startDownloading();
      }else if(result==null){
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Upload failed",timetoshow).show();
              }
          }
```

Comment: lol Main should be Italicized to represent it being static...oh well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a static method in DownloadManager

```
private static instance;

public void onCreate() {
    instance = this;
}

public static void startDownloading() {
    instance.downloadNow();
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing my brain in the right direction :) after so many nights of over caffination and 4 hours of sleep you start to forget that most things can be done with simple solutions:) I run the instance of my main class from inside the class that I used to build my own context out of so I just made the instance of the main class inside there static and call the method from in there like in my edited post up top there....thanks again dude :)

Answer (score 1):

onProgressUpdate() of AnsycTask will tell you about the progress  .so here you can  decide hewhat data you want to send to next activity .  in next activity deal with remaining not downloaded portion . thinks depends on server side implementation of data chunk .

your complete requirement will be required for more suggestions.

Comment: Oh yeah I hadnt thought about using that. But couldnt I get away with just calling the method in the onPostExecute()?

Answer (score 1):

Having processes hanging around from a dead Activity is dangerous, as it has a high potential to cause leaks. Why not start the `AsyncTask` in the Activity you intend to show progress? That would make the most sense.

Comment: Being that my app deals with a very high volume of images in different activities I had a bit of a problem cleaning up the leaks that showed themselves. Ive cleaned up all that I can see being that in my app Im building on 2.2 so I cant really tell whats sticking around bitmap wise in the heap. Ive used weakreferences where I was able to get away with it and other methods to prevent those kinds of image resource leaks that due to the requirements of my project were unavoidable. Ive been running that asynctask like that and it seems ok and not leaking....to much lol.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like below, if I'm not mistaken I think the `AsyncTask` has written `DownloadManager` class.
I hope you have the `AsyncTask` written as a InnerClass similar to this in that class.

```
private class InitTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {....
```

Also you should have to have a getter to return InitTask object,

```
public InitTask getInitTask(){
    return new InitTask();
}
```

So in the other class, you can call this like below,

```
new YourOtherClass().getInitTask().execute();
```

Comment: Oh yeah I have it doing just that. The problem is that once I start my asynctask I close the activity that started it and let it run in the background while the Main activity comes back into view.

Comment: I hope then it's better to use a Service.. Or else you can keep the AsyncTask class separately instead of a InnerClass and make use of it when ever you want.

Comment: Yeah all my download classes could be converted to services in the future but at the moment they are working fine. I am definitely looking into creating a service extended class to handle incoming updates from the server to the user at time intervals based on their selection. Ive got the psudocode for it mapped out but I have yet to build a class using service.....looks fun :)